# What does the BigCommerce webhook payload's hash field represent?

Tags: hash, bigcommerce, webhooks

What does the BigCommerce webhook payload's `hash` field represent?

Their example webhook payload from [the getting started page](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/webhooks-getting-started) does include the field, but that page doesn't otherwise discuss it, and I haven't been able to find any discussion of it elsewhere.

```
{
    "store_id": 11111,
    "producer":"stores/abcde",
    "scope":"store/order/statusUpdated",
    "data":        {
        "type": "order",
        "id":173331
    },
    "hash":"3f9ea420af83450d7ef9f78b08c8af25b2213637"
}
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476335/what-is-hash-field-in-the-bigcommerce-webhook